# How common are bacta tanks?

Tags: star-wars

I've come across the idea of bacta tanks in the extended universe, and my memory from the films is sketchy. As most of my reading about them has been from, well, back ground reading and not from any novels detailing them and that I don't think they're covered in detail in the film, I'd like to know, *how common are they?* Especially during the Great Jedi Purge?

Comment: I'd be willing to guess most hospitals have at least one tank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bacta was invented by the Vratix on the planet Thyferra in antiquity, with the galaxy at large learning of its properties around 4,100 BBY (src: The Essential Atlas). So by the time of ABY it became fairly widely used, though not 100% ubiquitous due to supply constraint.

Bacta was used for a while, but for a time shared the market with [Kolto](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kolto).

When Kolto supplies collapsed, Bacta became fully widely used.

Bacta was synthetic, but mostly produced on 1 planet, until the events of X-Wing novel "The Bacta War", when the Vratix finally exported the process off-planet.

Comment: True, it's just the one planet, but that's pretty much the only thing the planet does.  It makes a LOT of bacta.

Comment: @Jeff - wasn't there like millions of planets in the SWU? NOT enough Bakta :)

Comment: It doesn't take much, and the stuff doesn't go bad.  Sure, a bit is used in every injury, but the same tank can be used for a LONG time between refills.  They discuss this in _The Bacta War_, or possibly _The Krytos Trap_.